# Lambert W-function

Tags: special-functions, real-analysis

I asked this question [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218453/expressing-solution-to-an-inequality-with-lambert-w-function), but didn't get any answers. Maybe here someone can help.

I need to solve 
$$
\theta \rho^{\theta}+r \theta>v
$$

where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^{+}, -1 < r,v<1, \ 0<\rho<1$.

using Lambert W-function. I know solutions using Lambert/product log function to equations of the type $ a^z +z =b_1$ and $z a^z=b_2$, but this one I couldn't handle myself. Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Did you try a Taylor series?

Comment: I'm afraid they won't give good approximation as $r, \rho, v$ vary quite substantially

Comment: Well, after some playing around I guess there is no closed solution. However, introducing $x:= - \ln(\rho)\theta$ and $w:=-v/\ln(\rho)$ gets you rid of the $\rho$ and find some of the trivial situations easily. Also for $r=0$ or $v=0$ the solution is easy, of course. From there some Taylor expansion would do for a small range of parameter values, I guess.